# What is Fedora Workstation's system font?

Tags: fedora, fonts, visual-studio-code

I am publishing a couple V.S. Code extensions, and I already have a couple available for download in ["Microsoft's Visual Studio Marketplace"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/). Two of the extensions contribute a font-family setting, and ***I would like to assign the Fedora system font, as one of the fallback fonts***, in the list of fonts that is assigned as the default configuration for the settings contributed by the extensions. For what its worth, below is VS Code's default configuration for font-settings that don't require a "monospace" type-face.

###### *V.S. Codes Font-family Configurations Default Fallback Configuration:*

```
font-family: var("-apple-system, "Segoe UI", "Ubuntu", "Droid Sans", "sans-serif", monospace);
```

---

Above explains why I am asking this question. Below is the acttual question, asked in a very concise manner.

###### *What is Fedora Workstation's system font (or the font that I should use as a fallback for Fedora)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is Fedora Workstation's system font?

Fedora Linux 36 has just changed the default font to Noto:

> **Under-the-hood changes throughout Fedora Linux 36**
>
> - The Noto fonts are now used by default for many languages. This provides greater coverage for different character sets. For users who
>   write in the Malayalam script, the new Meera and RIT Rachana fonts are
>   now the default.

Source: [What’s new in Fedora Workstation 36 - Fedora Magazine](https://fedoramagazine.org/whats-new-fedora-36-workstation/)

> Previous version used DejaVu fonts for European and other language scripts. But not all languages are covered by DejaVu so there are also other fonts involved.

Source: [Fedora 36 Looking To Change Its Default Fonts - Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-36-Default-Fonts)

See Also: [Changes/DefaultToNotoFonts - Fedora Project Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/DefaultToNotoFonts)

Comment: Great answer. Thank you David.

Comment: Is this the font reported by `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No idea, I'm running Windows 7 :)

Comment: Just wondering ... I'm still on Fedora 35 and it reports `Cantarell`, although it does have the `Noto` fonts installed.  Maybe I'll preview it.  :-)

Comment: @rickhg12hs I believe Cantarell has always been the Gnome font on Fedora.